# Why does JMP occupy an ALU port on Intel CPUs?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, intel

Consider the direct unconditional near jump instruction JMP. As it only modifies EIP without consuming any operands (flags, registers, or memory) it can be fully resolved in the CPU front-end. As the following micro-benchmark indicates, on a Skylake CPU it can take less than 10 cycles to resolve a jump:

```asm
.globl _start
_start:
.rept 10000
        jmp .+3
        nop
.endr
        ud2
```

```shell
$ gcc -c t.s && ld t.o
$ perf stat -e cycles,instructions -e\ uops_dispatched_port.port_{0,1,5,6} ./a.out
./a.out: Illegal instruction

 Performance counter stats for './a.out':

            94,515      cycles:u
            10,002      instructions:u                   #    0.11  insn per cycle
               138       uops_dispatched_port.port_0:u
               152       uops_dispatched_port.port_1:u
               126       uops_dispatched_port.port_5:u
            10,232       uops_dispatched_port.port_6:u

       0.001461371 seconds time elapsed

       0.001111000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

At the same time, we see that jumps occupy port 6, making it unavailable for arithmetic instructions. This is surprising, because there is no apparent reason why a direct JMP would need an ALU port, and Intel has been eliminating unnecessary use of execution ports: on Sandy Bridge, NOPs and `XOR same, same` do not occupy a port, and Ivy Bridge added move elimination.

This appears to be finally rectified on Icelake, where direct jumps do not occupy a port [[uops.info](https://uops.info/html-instr/JMP_Rel32.html)] and direct calls have one fewer executed uop [[uops.info](https://uops.info/html-instr/CALL_NEAR_Rel32.html)].

Is there some subtlety that makes a JMP different from a NOP in the processor back-end, which could make it difficult for Intel to stop it tying up an ALU until Icelake?

Comment: It's a relative jump, so it needs to add the immediate displacement to RIP.  Maybe they previously used the port 6 ALU to do that addition, instead of giving the front end its own adder for that purpose?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think that sounds like something that could happen on Atoms, but not on the high-performance designs, were one 64-bit adder seems like peanuts compared to the other bits of branch handling machinery in the front-end. Latency estimate from my experiment does not seem to support that either.

Comment: Speculation: Having all control flow operations "resolve" at the same point/port(s) in the pipeline may have been easier even if the target and condition is known earlier for jumps. Moving jump handling entirely to the front-end may not have been considered worth the effort; code with frequent(ish) jumps and high ILP is probably not common. (Changes to control flow handling not only have to be revalidated for architectural correctness but also for avoiding microarchitectural efficiency gotchas and side channels.) An optimization might also be reserved for when other improvements are smaller.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's not very plausible, and greatly increases branch latency if the existence (and actual target) of the branch wasn't predicted by branch-prediction.  A simple adder in the front-end can re-steer the pipeline earlier; e.g. perf events like `baclears.any`.  Even in-order pipelines like classic MIPS have a separate adder for PC calculations on branches instead of feeding it through the ALU.  (Since the ALU might be busy evaluating the branch *condition* for conditional relative branches, which are also a thing in x86).

Comment: Paul's comment makes a lot of sense: handling it in an ALU like a conditional branch might solve some corner cases, or avoid the need for extra logic somewhere else.